# How to destroy jQuery validation and any further attempts at submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code for the jQuery validation plugin.... basically on submit, I slide everything up & fade it out... the only problem is, if you're quick enough, you can submit the form multiple times. How can I make sure that any presses of the enter key on the input (or clicks on that submit button) will not submit further?

Basically what happens, is that the form will load up the url in the action attribute when no javascript is there, so purely unbinding doesn't work... (even if it did, I can always press enter / click fast enough to get it to do a couple more....)

```
jQuery('.desired').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    wrapper: "div",
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.hide().appendTo(element.parent()).hide().slideDown();
    },
    errorClass: 'help-text',
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        var $ = jQuery;

        var url   = $(form).attr('action');
        var query = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: query,
            success: function() {


                $("<p class='help-jquery'><b>Thanks</b>")
                    .insertAfter(jQuery(form))
                    .css('height', function(i,h) {
                        $(this).hide()
                        return h;
                    });

                // $(form).css('height', $(form).height());
                $(form).slideUp('slow');
                $(form).fadeOut({ queue: false, duration: 'slow' });


                // $('.help-jquery').fadeIn('slow');

                $('.help-jquery')
                    .css('opacity', 0)
                    .slideDown('fast')
                    .animate(
                        { opacity: 1 },
                        { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
                    );

                //$('.desired submit').click(function(){
                    //return false;
                //});
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error: did not submit properly');
            },
            complete: function(e) {
                //$('.desired').unbind('submit');
                //e.preventDefault();
                //return false;
            }
        });


    },
    success: function(error,element){
    },
    highlight: function(error){
        // This empty function needs to be here for this to work
    }

});
```

Comment: See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `unbind()`, it solves half of your problem because it will effectively suppress validation on form submission.

To solve the second half, you only have to neuter the form's `submit` event after unbinding, by registering the appropriate handler:

```
$(form).unbind("submit").submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems like it works, but only for clicking the submit button: pressing enter still allows me to trigger it multiple times.

Comment: I had this in the same place as my commented out unbind code.... it needed to be directly in the submit handler, right under the Ajax call. Thanks!

Comment: **FYI: The plugin now contains a [`.destroy()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/).**

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable, like this:

```
var didValidate = false;

if(!didValidate) {
    jQuery('.desired').validate({
        //... your code here
    });
}
```

In your AJAX success function, set `didValidate` to true.

Comment: right now, the ajax is nested inside the validate. So that wouldn't work?

Comment: Nope, that would work. The catch is, that will only work once, which is what you want. The way it works is, once you successfully validate, `didValidate` is set to false. Once it's false, you won't be able to validate again, no matter how many times you hit Enter. :)

Comment: that's the thing: the validate doesn't need to run again to be active.... once you run it, it watches all inputs and validates them forever... notice how there is no code running that validate code multiple times, it just happens by itself. What I need to do, is remove whatever it attached... I guess is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the [`.destroy()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/) method.

This question and its answers are quite old.  So since that time, the developer has added a `.destroy()` method to detach the validation plugin from the form.

> *Destroys this instance of validator freeing up resources and unregistering events.*

```
// Initialize the validation plugin on your form

var validator = $("#myform").validate();

// Remove validation from your form

validator.destroy();

// After this point `#myform` is back to its original state without validation.
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/

---

To stop multiple submissions, disable the `submit` button within the plugin's `submitHandler` function.  *(The `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid and you've already clicked the submit button.)*

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // validation & submit success, so disable submit button
    $("#yourSubmitButton").prop('disabled', true);
    // your ajax code here
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For those stuck on an earlier version, you can patch it in like so: `jQuery.validator.prototype.destroy = <the destroy function from https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js>`

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable that is 1 or 0. before you do any validation, check that the variable is equal to 0. If it isn't 0, do nothing. If it is, continue. Once the validation passes, set the variable to 1 so that the validation cannot occur again.

Comment: so this is an actual jQuery plugin.... once you set it, it just works until the page reloads.... so I need a way to be like $('.desired').validateDestroy();

...or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use event namespaces:

The name following the '.' let's you target handlers more specifically.

This at the top of the submit handler:

```
$(form).bind('submit.temp_submit_hold', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); //added this in case the plugin's handler func uses bubbling
    return false;
} );
```

This at the top of the complete callback for the ajax call:

```
$('.desired').unbind('submit.temp_submit_hold');
```

A little more explanation after seeing your comments in complete. The time to preventDefault is immediately after your onsubmit handler starts working. On complete is when you want to enable it again. So we bind a func that stops it with prevent default and then unbind it to toggle behavior. I also added stopPropagation in case the plugin uses delegation/bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest is to add something like this to your submithandler

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    var $ = jQuery;
    if ( $.data(form, "submit") ) > "" return false;
    $.data(form, "submit", "in progress");
    //  .. the rest of your handler
}
```

If you want to allow the form to submitted again later, remove the .data() on success.